# Change the cursor position from top to bottom in a Flutter textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, textformfield, flutter-textformfield

I need to change the position of the cursor inside the textformfield. I managed to reduce the height of the cursor with 1, but the position of the cursor remains top. I was not be able to move it to the bottom.

I wanted to achieve this:

[image]

But what I achieve is:

[image]

Is there a way to do it in Flutter?

My code sample

```dart
TextFormField(
  style: TextStyle(
    color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.color,
    fontSize: 14,
  ),
  minLines: 1,
  maxLines: 1,
  maxLength: 300,
  cursorColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
  textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
  cursorHeight: 1,
  cursorWidth: 15,
);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TextFormField has the property of `height` inside the `style` - you can apply 0.0 on height to achieve your output. also from `bottom` or `top` padding you can use `contentPadding` so you can apply or remove the padding from top left to bottom right from cursor to input line :[image: output]

```
 return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.color,
          fontSize: 26,
          height: 0.0, 
        ),
        minLines: 1,
        maxLength: 300,
        cursorColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
        textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
        cursorHeight: 1,
        cursorWidth: 15,
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, border: InputBorder.none),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add style in your TextFormField
height: 0.1

```
TextFormField(
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall?.color,
            fontSize: 14,
            height: 0.1, // you need to add this only
          ),
          minLines: 1,
          maxLines: 1,
          maxLength: 300,
          cursorColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
          textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
          cursorHeight: 1,
          cursorWidth: 15,
        ),
```

For CupertinoTextField

```
CupertinoTextField(
          placeholder: 'search',
          style: TextStyle(
            height: 0.1,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
          cursorHeight: 1,
          cursorWidth: 15,
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

- If you don't set cursorHeight to the height of the font, it won't work as expected when the font gets bigger.
- This will help componentize based on dynamic font

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var fontSize = 50.0;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: fontSize),
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 1,
            maxLength: 300,
            cursorColor: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
            cursorHeight: fontSize,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would want to add to [rahulVFlutterAndroid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75028976/change-the-cursor-position-from-top-to-bottom-in-flutter-textfield/75057045#75057045).

#### Why is this observed?

Because, by default, the cursor starts from left top of the textField. By changing the height of the cursor, the cursor moved to the top left position.

#### How can we overcome this?

Use *height* and set it to `0.0`:

```
body:TextFormField(
        style: TextStyle(
          /* ... */
          height: 0.0, /*   This should solve your problem  */
        ),
        /* ... */
     );
```